# Log Shell cakephp

Tags: shell, cakephp-2

Tenho um arquivo SHELL no cakephp conforme abaixo:

```
<?php
class AtualizarIndicadoresNormaisShell extends AppShell {
    public function atualizar() {
        //Chama model e sua action
        ClassRegistry::init('DadoIndicadoresNormal')->atualizarIndicadoresNormais();
    }
}
```

Ele chama a model abaixo em atualizarIndicadoresNormais():

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class DadoIndicadoresNormal extends AppModel {
    ...
    function atualizarIndicadoresNormais() {
        App::import('Controller', 'DadosIndicadoresNormais');
        $atualizar = new DadosIndicadoresNormaisController;
        $atualizar->cronAtualizar();
    }
}
```

Nela chamo uma action do controller chamada cronAtualizar().

Dentro da Action do Controller, como faço para exibir uma mensagem através do Shell? 
Usei conforme abaixo mas retorna erro. Pois ela só funciona dentro do arquivo Shell. Podem me ajudar? Ou se tiver como salvar um log de erro.

```
 $this->out
```

Answer (score 0):

Realmente não é possível enviar uma mensagem para o terminal a partir de um model ou controller. 
A melhor saída nessa caso é realmente utilizar um log alternativo para você acompanhar as saídas.
Nesse caso basta você adicionar as configurações em *config*, exemplo:

```
// Configure tmp/logs/shop.log to receive the two configured types (log levels), but only
// those with `orders` and `payments` as scope
CakeLog::config('shop', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'types' => array('warning', 'error'),
    'scopes' => array('orders', 'payments'),
    'file' => 'shop.log',
));

// Configure tmp/logs/payments.log to receive the two configured types, but only
// those with `payments` as scope
CakeLog::config('payments', array(
    'engine' => 'SyslogLog',
    'types' => array('info', 'error', 'warning'),
    'scopes' => array('payments')
));
```

Depois para fazer a chamada de forma estática para gravar no log:

```
CakeLog::warning('This gets written only to shops stream', 'orders');
CakeLog::warning('This gets written to both shops and payments streams', 'payments');
```

Essa informações podem ser encontradas melhor na própria documentação do CakePHP na area de [Logging](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#CakeLog::configured).